# Stack Clone Problem: .NET Bug or Expected Behaviour?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I came across this problem when cloning a stack... not sure if it's a .NET bug or expected behaviour.  Opinions?

```
Dim myStack As New Stack(Of Integer)({2,1,3})
Response.Write(String.Join(",",myStack.Clone) & "<br>" & String.Join(",",myStack.Clone.Clone))
```

output:

```
2,1,3
3,1,2 <- I expected 2,1,3
```

Comment: My opinion is that it is not a .net bug.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile for me. Are you using some interesting extension method? Can you post a short but complete console app which demonstrates this?

Comment: You sure you are not using the non-generic Stack (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx)? The generic stack doesn't have a Clone-method.

Comment: @alun: Even then, it looks like he's using a property here while the non-generic `Clone()` is a method.

Comment: You're right Jon... I added .Clone to Stack(Of T) in my extensions... I had forgotten and thought .Clone was native to Stack(Of T) - thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a .Net Bug.  The `Stack(Of T)` type doesn't posses a `Clone` method or property.  This is demonstrated by the following code which doesn't compile on a standard VB.Net console project

```
Dim stack As New Stack(Of Integer)({2, 1, 3})
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", stack.Clone))
```

The `Clone` method being bound to must be an extension method defined somewhere in your project.  The bug or by design behavior lies there.